# Android how to arrange multiple rows in one HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm searching for a solution to set up multiple rows in a scrollview.

I have  15 buttons (3*5) and want to scroll to the right so there are another 15 buttons.

What I already got: all buttons are in one huge row ( at least, scrolling iself worked ).

Then I tried to set the HorizontalScrollView on the highest layer (line #1 in XML) and after that a LinearLayout that contains 3 further LinearLayouts so the tree looks like this:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
  <LinearLayout
     <LinearLayout
       (buttonABCDEF)
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
       (button01234)
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
       (button56789)
     </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

What I get then is a (~80x80) rectangle (the linear layout in the ScrollView) that shows a text (the first view in my layout) and a button (buttonA - the first one) that is so stemmed (by whatever) that every character is written into a new line. (The amount of letters= amount of lines= button height). This isn't scrollable at all.

I'm trying to post only the code that is relevant. Note: that android:layout stuff is not important for you since it is not working in a linear layout:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView

                   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
       android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"


         tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
        >



         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation='vertical'  > 
             android:layout_width="9dp"




         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent" > 
             android:layout_width="9dp"




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       android:text="text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonB"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
          android:width="70dp"
        android:text="A" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonD"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonD"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonD"
           android:width="70dp"
      android:text="B" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonE"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonE"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonE"
        android:text="C" />


</LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout

             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    > 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
          android:background="@drawable/eins"
        android:text="0" /> 
/LinearLayout>
/LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it making the layout completely new. Even that of course not the best way, it seemed faster than searching for errors